# Java: Printing triangles and spaces by calling methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm stuck on this question:

> Printing stars and spaces
>
> Define a method called printSpaces(int number) that produces the
>   number of spaces specified by number. The method does not print the
>   line break.
>
> You will also have to either copy the printStars method your previous
>   answer or reimplement it in this exercise template. Printing a
>   right-leaning triangle
>
> Create a method called printTriangle(int size) that uses printSpaces
>   and printStars to print the correct triangle. So the method call
>   printTriangle(4) should print the following: Sample output

```
>    *
>   **
>  ***
> ****
```

I cannot get the spaces thing to work on the first question, and I'm totally lost on making the recursive triangle. I see that lots of answers are using for loops, however the class I'm working in wants them done as methods. I can't comprehend how to properly translate that. I got the triangle the other way around with this:

```
public class Test072 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(4);
    }


    public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        int numSize = 0;
        while (numSize < size) {
            printStars(numSize);
            numSize++;
        }
    }

    public static void printStars(int number) {
        int numStar = 0;
        while (numStar <= number) {
            System.out.print("*");
            numStar++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Once we started adding spaces in, I totally got lost and have no idea how to call what and when. I don't know how to properly call the space method into the triangle method as they are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    int numSize = 0;
    while (numSize < size) {
        printSpaces(size - numSize - 1);
        printStars(numSize);
        numSize++;
    }
}
public static void printSpaces(int number) {
    int numSpaces = 0;
    while (numSpaces < number) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        numSpaces++;
    }
}
    public static void printStars(int number) {
        int numStar = 0;
        while (numStar <= number) {
            System.out.print("*");
            numStar++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I'm having trouble understanding is how you got the printTriangle portion to work. Could you do a quick rundown of what's happening from printSpaces to numSize++?

Comment: Method printSpaces only prints out spaces for specified number of times. It's just simple while loop, so I don't think you need any explanation about how it works inside, so I will go straight to the printTriangle method. 
As you can see in the sample output, first row has has always 1 star and 3 spaces, second row has 2 stars and 2 spaces, third row has 3 stars and 1 space and finally the last (fourth) row has 0 spaces and 4 stars. That said, when we call our printSpaces method, we pass (size - numSize - 1) as an argument. So let's follow the printTriangle method invocation step by step.

Comment: Initially a numSize variable has value 0 and we call printSpaces(4 (argument passed from main method) - 0 - 1) = printSpaces(3). That's what we wanted, 3 spaces. Then we have printSpaces(2), printSpaces(1) and printSpaces(0). I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: @farmac:  Next time, put the explanation in the answer, rather than in comments.  A good explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//printStars is printing "number" numbers of stars on one line with a line break

public static void printStars(int number) {
    for(int i=1;i<=number;i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//printSpaces print "number" number of spaces on one line
public static void printSpaces(int number) {

    for(int i=1;i<=number;i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

public static void printTriangle(int size) {

    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        printSpaces(size-i);
        printStars(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code only answer is great. Can you add comments to explain what the code is doing?